# Possible alternate coordinate system

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates

I am dealing with some geographic data from Brazil and it comes in a coordinate system I am not familiar with. It is not lat/long. I am working with the state Rio Grande do Norte where the x coordinates range from about 250000 to 620000 and the y coordinates are from about 9220000 to 9460000.

For reference, the lat/long ranges of Rio Grande do Norte should be about -38 to -35 for x and -7 to -4.5 for y. (The ranges in both systems only include the mainland)

How can I identify this coordinate system and also convert to lat/long, if possible?

Comment: Within the properties of the layer, it doesn't say what coordinate system it is in? Where did you get the data from?

Comment: http://projfinder.com/

Comment: Is there a ReadMe file that came with the data when you downloaded it? I've often found that when the CRS is unspecified, some other file in the batch download will have that information.

Comment: Looks like a UTM zone, maybe 24S (south). Could be a few different GeodCRS though.